# Issue with WPF Image Control Not Displaying Images with 24-bit Depth and Size Greater Than Approximately 16300 Pixels

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm encountering an issue with the WPF Image control where it fails to display images with a bit depth of 24 and a size larger than approximately 16300 pixels on certain computers.

Here's the XAML code displaying a blank PNG image with dimensions 22400*3200 and a bit depth of 24:

```
<Image Stretch="None" Source="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LiveIsLive/temp-upload/main/BitDepth24Test.png" />
```

I've conducted tests on 7 different computers. Out of these, 4 computers can open the image correctly. However, on the remaining 3 computers, the interface remains blank after opening, and the entire application becomes unresponsive, without throwing any exceptions.

Interestingly, when I converted the image's bit depth to 32, it displayed correctly on all machines:

```
<Image Stretch="None" Source="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LiveIsLive/temp-upload/main/BitDepth32Test.png" />
```

If anyone is interested, they can download the test program I created here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LiveIsLive/temp-upload/main/LargeSizeImageTest.zip

I'm seeking assistance to understand the cause of this issue. Is there a possibility to resolve this without modifying the program?

Comment: That's a lot more than 16300 pixels.  Ensure your app runs in 64-bit mode.

Comment: There is a possibility that this format is not the default for Windows and you need to register the corresponding codec. In this case, perhaps some computers have the required codec, but others do not.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/imaging-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @HansPassant The target platform is "Any CPU", and uncheck "Preferred 32-bit" to build

Comment: @EldHasp The image for testing is created by "Paint.NET" and the codec is png which is the one of inner codec of WPF/.NET

Comment: Focus a bit on the hang.  It is a sign of over-active anti-malware, trying to scan a .exe that just got copied onto a machine.  Since the .exe got bulked-up by a large bitmap resource, that can take many minutes.  So temporarily disable it to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Next assumption.
When you access a picture, it is downloaded from the specified WEB address. Maybe the reason is in the download? It is not carried out by WPF, but by the OS.
For diagnostics, download the image to your computer and set it to an absolute local path.

Comment: Please add the specifications of the machines on which you ran your app. cpu, memory, os version and .net version